# TCP acknowledgment payload

Tags: cisco, routing, tcp

In TCP/IP communication, we know that when a sender sends a packet containing some data, the receiver has to return an ACK packet. Does this ACK packet has to carry the same payload that the receiver got or it is just turning on ACK flag in the header and the next serial number?

Comment: Actually, TCP does not normally send an ACK for each segment (not packet) containing data. TCP sends an ACK for each window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is just turning on ACK flag in the header and the next serial number

Yup.

Repeating the payload would just lead to unnecessary duplicating of data that has to be carried across the network. The Acknowledgement number itself is sufficient to tell the initial sender exactly what bits of data have been received.

Comment: Can the receiver send the ack segment with payload? I mean, the ack segment is used as both "confirmation" and "sending data"(thus will wait for an ack from remote.